# Plugging out USB in safe manner?

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb, veracrypt

Do I have to plug out USB devices in safe manner (clicking in taskbar icon at right down corner of Windows) if I did not change data on the device, just read the data ?

As I understand this safe way ensure that we do not lost the data that was recently written to the usb pendrive.

Does it matter if I did not any changes, just read ?

Should I also decrypt a disk ciphered with VeraCrypt if I just read the data from such a disk ?

edit about decryption:

I mean lets say I have USB with veracrypt container file or even the whole disk cyphered. Then lets say I have mounted veracrypt cyphered container and read some data. Then I am in hurry and I am wondering if I can just plug out USB or do I need to exit all the application, then dismount container, then unplug USB in safe manner. This is quite short but annoying behaviour and if I am using at once 3 usb with containers then it takes more than minute every time. I know I should do this way if I wrote into the disk to be sure data have been written, but if I just read and opened open office with document from container then is the risk of something got broken (data or usb) ? This is actually what I wonder. Thanks for answers. By the way as Veracrypt wrote - the data is all the time ciphered at the disk, even during usage, but decrypted copy is stored in memory at live usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it matter if I did not any changes, just read ?

It depends on the filesystem, some of them make writes every time they're mounted as writeable (saving the mount time, updating the mount count, etc). And whether or not any programs or the OS are making changes without you knowing (updating file access times, writing lock files or temporary files...). Some filesystems are left in a "dirty" state if they're not unmounted cleanly, if you're lucky there's no data loss and it's just the mounted/clean/dirty flag that's not set.

If you could mount the filesystem as read-only, and no writes at all are made to the drive, then it *should* be safe to just yank it out. But safely removing is quick & easy, so why even risk data loss?

> Should I also decrypt a disk ciphered with VeraCrypt if I just read the data from such a disk ?

You can't read any (decrypted) data without decrypting it in the first place

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have edite my question to clarify about veracrypt scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think its best you know what happens when you safely unplug a usb. By doing that taskbar action you describe you let your system know:

- its time to stop all active writes to the device.
- all programs that can access the device are alerted that its going
  away, and will start the necessary proceedures (if necessary)

If a program fails to take action, and is still holding files open, you are alerted. In a perfect condition the answer would be yes, go ahead remove it, but there can be some background program still using that device, and you might lose whatever files he is interacting with.

I have personally tried this with an old USB pen drive, and I never got any sort of corruptions for over 5 years, but if you value what its stored why not take those extra 5 seconds.

---

Short answer to your other question, if the disk has any sort of encryption there should be no way to read it without decryption.

Comment: Thanks for answer, that is good way of explanation. I have edited my post about cyphered way. In the general question you have written: "but there can be some background program still using that device, and you might lose whatever files he is interacting with." Do you mean that I can lose the original file at the disk at all or just the exact changes that I made while this specific current interaction of such a program done with such a file ?